# Binding a variable amount of inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I would like to post a form with a variable number of check-boxes, so in Model-biding i would receive an array or `IEnumerable` with each `checkbox` name and it's value.

**What I pretend:**

```
public class ItemsChecked{  
    public IEnumerable<string> Names{get; set;}  
    public IEnumerable<bool> Checked{get; set;}  
    //maybe organized in some other way
}

//In view  
@model IEnumerable<Tuple<string,bool>>

@foreach(var role in Model)
{  
<input name="@role.Item1" type="checkbox" checked="@role.Item2"/>
}
```

Is there any way to bind this to the ItemsChecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Can't bind array to view model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7631212/136717).

You can find a link there to Phil Haacks explanation on how to do it.  Link is at 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I actually gone through that page before posting the question. Thanks for answer.