# ASP.NET MVC 5 model binding list is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I stuck on this issue for a while..

I've created a simple view model:

```
public class AddTranslationViewModel
{
    public List<ProjectTranslation> ProjectTranslations { get; set; }
    public AddTranslationViewModel()
    {
        ProjectTranslations = new List<ProjectTranslation>();
    }
}
```

ProjectTranslation class:

```
public class ProjectTranslation
{
    public int ProjectTranslationId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

A simple view which uses the AddTranslationViewModel

```
<table class="table">

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectTranslations)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProjectTranslationId)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Language.LanguageCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

and finally my POST Method:

```
    public ViewResult AddTranslation(AddTranslationViewModel projectTranslations)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //...
        }
        return View(projectTranslations);
    }
```

The idea is very basic, I want to show a list of items where it should be possible to change/edit the values.

However, the model binding is not working, the projectsTranslations param in the HTTPPost-Method AddTranslation is always empty.

What's the mistake here?

Comment: make sure you are posting to this page by using a <form method="POST">

Comment: Tried kind of everything, at the moment it is: @using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: is the name of Get and Post Action methods is same? and confirm if you used [HttpPost] on your post action method

Comment: Yes, the names are the same. It's jumping into the post method, 'only' the binding in the object is not set - CONFIRMED, yeah, i use the HttpPost tag

Comment: I tried to replicate it but couldn't. viewModel parameter in Post method is not null. Try creating a new project and do as less as possible to replicate the same. You might see the mistake

Comment: Thanks for your help! Bad title for the topic (I changed it) the viewModel param isn't null, but the list nested in the viewModel object is empty.

Comment: Tried to change the foreach in the view to a for loop...same issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Binding to a list of object requires creating input field structure with names containing indexes, i.e:

```
<input type="text" name="YourArrayOrList[0].SomeProperty" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="YourArrayOrList[0].SomeOtherProperty" value="321" />
<input type="text" name="YourArrayOrList[1].SomeProperty" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="YourArrayOrList[1].SomeOtherProperty" value="321" />
```

Moreover, you need to point the form to the proper Action Method in your Controller using Razor's `Html.BeginFrom` method ([see documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)).
In you case it should look like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddTranslation","YourControllerName"))
{
    for (int i=0;i<Model.ProjectTranslations.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProjectTranslations[i].ProjectTranslationId)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectTranslations[i].Language.LanguageCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectTranslations[i].Title)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

**If your method is not edit, but CREATE method, then obviously your List in model will have 0 elements. In this case, change the stop condition in for loop to desired count.**

Keep in mind that this topic was discussed many times before:

[ASP.NET MVC bind array in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080355/asp-net-mvc-bind-array-in-model)

[ASP.NET MVC - Can't bind array to view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631212/asp-net-mvc-cant-bind-array-to-view-model)

Comment: Thank you, already changed the foreach to a for loop. I had to change the ViewModel Parameter in the AddTranslation Method to a List of ProjectTranslation - after that, it worked.

Comment: You can have complex model as a parameter, there is no need for changing it to List<T>. Built-in model binder will handle nested properties properly if your view generates proper input names.

Comment: The use of a foreach loop instead of a for loop was the thing that gave me issues.