# Selected Checkboxes are not showing up in the HttpPost action method in asp.net core mvc 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to print all the selected checkboxes in the `[HttpPost]` action method. But, I'm always getting  count as 0. Can someone suggest me where I'm doing wrong?

Below is my `Category` model class.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public bool CheckboxAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Since this is sample program, I've used `CategoryData` class like below to bind to checkbox list controls.

```
public class CategoryData
{
    public CategoryData()
    {
    }

    public List<Category> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { CategoryId = 1, CategoryName = "Beverages", CheckboxAnswer = true },
                new Category { CategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "Condiments", CheckboxAnswer = false },
                new Category { CategoryId = 3, CategoryName = "Confections", CheckboxAnswer = true },
                new Category { CategoryId = 4, CategoryName = "Dairy Products", CheckboxAnswer = false }
            };
            return categories;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the View: `GetSelectedCheckBoxes.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<Practice.MVC.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Get Selected CheckBoxes";
}
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="GetSelectedCheckBoxes" method="post">
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@category.CheckboxAnswer" />
        <label asp-for="@category.CategoryId">@category.CategoryName</label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@category.CategoryId" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@category.CategoryName" />
    }
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Below is the `[HttpGet]` version of my `Controller` action method.

```
    public IActionResult GetSelectedCheckBoxes()
    {
        var categories = new CategoryData().Categories;
        return View(categories);
    }
```

Below is the `[HttpPost]` version of my `Controller` action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetSelectedCheckBoxes(List<Category> categories)
    {
        string selectedCheckboxes = string.Empty;
        string notSelectedCheckboxes = string.Empty;
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            if (category.CheckboxAnswer)
                selectedCheckboxes += category.CategoryName + ", ";
            if (!category.CheckboxAnswer)
                notSelectedCheckboxes += category.CategoryName + ", ";
        }
        return Content(selectedCheckboxes + " ------ " + notSelectedCheckboxes);
    }
```

As you can see in the below screenshot, I'm not getting `categories` as parameter
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 5 model binding list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238179/asp-net-mvc-5-model-binding-list-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use code below:

```
@model IList<Practice.MVC.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Get Selected CheckBoxes";
}
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="GetSelectedCheckBoxes" method="post">
     
        @*@foreach (var category in Model)*@
        @for(int i=0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
        {
            @Html.CheckBox("categories[" + i + "].CheckboxAnswer", Model[i].CheckboxAnswer)

            <label asp-for="@Model[i].CategoryId">@Model[i].CategoryName</label>

            @Html.Hidden("categories[" + i + "].CategoryId", Model[i].CategoryId)
            @Html.Hidden("categories[" + i + "].CategoryName", Model[i].CategoryName)
        }
   
    <input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

To be the MVC binding work properly it's necessary to use indexing for the collection items.

[image]

Therefore, to make code shorter in the fragment above the `IEnumerable` is replaced by the `IList` and the `for` is used instead of the `foreach`.

In additional, the `<input>` tag helper generates the `id` and `name` HTML attributes for the expression name specified in the `asp-for` attribute. But in this case the index will not included to the 'id' and the `name`. See [The Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-input-tag-helper)

This is why the [HTML Helper alternatives to Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#html-helper-alternatives-to-input-tag-helper) is used.